# VB Method to create a zip file for a folder

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to VB programming. I am trying to create a zip file using vb with sub folders in it, that one of the sub folders need not be included in the zip file created.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Function Compress(ByVal fileToCompress As FileInfo) As Boolean

    Dim _Compress As Boolean

    Using originalFileStream As FileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead()
        If (File.GetAttributes(fileToCompress.FullName) And FileAttributes.Hidden) <> FileAttributes.Hidden And fileToCompress.Extension <> ".gz" Then
            Using compressedFileStream As FileStream = File.Create(fileToCompress.FullName + ".gz")
                Using compressionStream As GZipStream = New GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress)
                    originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressionStream)
                    Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.",
                                      fileToCompress.Name, fileToCompress.Length.ToString(), compressedFileStream.Length.ToString())
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    End Using

    _Compress = File.Exists(fileToCompress.FullName + ".gz")


    Return _Compress

End Function
```